# Transformation unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, transformation

I'm learning unity by the book "Unity game development in 24 hours". The book says:

- Translation: Translation is a inert transformation. That means any changes applied after it won't be affected.
- Scaling: Scaling effectively changes the size of the local coordinate grid. Basically, when you scale an object to be larger, you are really scaling the local coordinate system to be larger. This causes the object to seem to grow. This change is multiplicative. For example, if an object is scaled to 1 (its natural, default size) and then translated 5 units along the x axis, the object appears to move 5 units to the right. If the same object were to be scaled to 2, however, then translating 5 units on the x axis would result in the object appearing to move 10 units to the right. This is because the local coordinate system is now double the size and 5 times 2 equals 10. Inversely, if the object were scaled to .5 and then moved, it would appear to only move 2.5 units (.5 x 5 = 2.5)

I tried to experiment this two effects but it didn't work that way. To the Translation, I can apply any changes after it. And to the Scaling, it scaled the local coordinate system in multiplicative way but it didn't multi the affect of translation. Am I understand this wrong or it's the book?

Answer (score 2):

Translating (using `Transform.Translate` method) means moving object's transform by some vector. Simple as that.
Local scale is little bit more complicated. It scales not only the object itself, but all objects, that are children of it. And the distance moved is relative - if you have a cube that's 1x1x1 in size and you move it by 1 unit, it will move its full length. If, however, you scale it by 2 and than move it by 1 unit, it moves only half its size.

According to what you wrote, the book is probably really bad source to learn Unity3D. Try doing some official tutorials, they are really good and explain the basics really well. [This one](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-roguelike-tutorial) is pretty good, [this one](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/survival-shooter-tutorial) as well. And remember, anytime you are in doubt with Unity. try to search their really good documentation first.

Comment: It actually worked like you said. Thanks for your help and suggestion! I'll check out the tutorials